# How to merge data in stata

Tags: merge, stata

I'm learning stata, and trying to understand merging. Can someone explain the difference between different kinds of merging to me? (1:1, 1:m, m:1, m:m)?

Comment: The `merge` command is documented extensively in the Stata Data-Management Reference Manual accessible from the PDF Documentation item in Stata's Help menu.

Answer (score 2):

In case the [Stata manual](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?merge) is unclear, here's a quick overview.

First, it's important to clear up the terminology.

A `merge` basically connects rows in two datasets (Stata calls them `observations`) based on a specified variable or list of variables, called `key` variables. You have to start with one dataset already in memory (Stata calls this the `master` dataset), and you `merge` another dataset to it (the other dataset is called the `using` dataset). What you're left with is a single dataset containing all of the variables from the `master`, and any variable from the `using` that didn't already exist in `master`. It also generates a new variable called `_merge` indicating whether there were rows in `master` that weren't in `using` or vice versa. The merged dataset (unless otherwise specified) will contain all rows from `master` and `using`, regardless of whether the key variables matched between the two.

The concept of a "unique identifier" is important. If a variable (or combination of variables) has a different value in every row, it uniquely identifies rows. This is important for the details about 1:1, 1:m etc.

- 1:1 means the key variable provides unique identifiers in both datasets. You will be left with all of the rows from both datasets in memory.
- 1:m means the key variable in the `master` dataset uniquely identifies rows, but the key variable from the `using` dataset doesn't. You will still be left with all of the rows from both datasets, but if a key variable has duplicate observations in the using dataset, the `master` dataset will gain duplicates to match them.
- m:1 is the opposite of 1:m. The key variable in the `master` dataset doesn't uniquely identify rows, but the key variable in the `using` dataset does.
- m:m is kind of weird. The key variable doesn't uniquely identify rows in either dataset, so you will be left with duplicated rows from both sides.

Example:

```
** make a dataset and save as a tempfile called `b'. Note that k uniquely identifies rows
set obs 3 
gen k = _n
gen b = "b"
list
   +-------+
   | k   b |
   |-------|
1. | 1   b |
2. | 2   b |
3. | 3   b |
   +-------+

tempfile b
save `b'

** make another dataset and merge `b' to it. Note that k uniquely identifies rows

set obs 3 
gen k = _n
gen a = "a"
list
   +-------+
   | k   a |
   |-------|
1. | 1   a |
2. | 2   a |
3. | 3   a |
   +-------+

merge 1:1 k using `b'
list
   +-------------------------+
   | k   a   b        _merge |
   |-------------------------|
1. | 1   a   b   matched (3) |
2. | 2   a   b   matched (3) |
3. | 3   a   b   matched (3) |
   +-------------------------+


** make another dataset and merge `b' to it. Note that k does not uniquely identify rows and that k=2 and k=3 do not exist in the master dataset
clear
set obs 3 
gen k = 1
gen a = "a"
list
   +-------+
   | k   a |
   |-------|
1. | 1   a |
2. | 1   a |
3. | 1   a |
   +-------+
merge m:1 k using `b'
list
   +----------------------------+
   | k   a   b           _merge |
   |----------------------------|
1. | 1   a   b      matched (3) |
2. | 1   a   b      matched (3) |
3. | 1   a   b      matched (3) |
4. | 2       b   using only (2) |
5. | 3       b   using only (2) |
   +----------------------------+
```